# In client side javascript how to get the result of node express router method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my node application from express router method i need to send some result to the client side.How can i get that result in client side without using socket.io.

app.js

```
  var express=require('express');
  var app=express();
  app.configure(function(){
     app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
 app.listen(8011);

 app.get('/',function(req,res){

    //from here i need to send some result to the client side..Without using socket.io framework how can i send the data to the client side then how to get that data in client side. 

 });
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) (for sending plain strings) or [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) (for rendering and sending entire pages/views)?

Comment: @apsillers ok but i dont know how to get the result in client side..

Comment: @apsillers depending upon the result i need do something in client side.

Comment: Express is a Web server. If you've successfully loaded the page, you have the response (i.e., the page *is* the response). If you need to poll the server for data repeatedly using JavaScript, you need to use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Yup, apsillers is right. Response is only sent once in the form of html page or other content. Perhaps you can include your result in the response itself.